# Segfault when inserting a new element into a sorted linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am using the following function to insert a new node into a sorted linked list of integers

```
 // Insert new element
template <class Type>
bool list<Type> :: Insert (const Type& NewElement)
{
    Node *NewNode, *TempNext, *TempPrevious;
    NewNode = new Node;
    NewNode -> Element = NewElement;

    for (TempNext = Head; TempNext != NULL; TempPrevious = TempNext, TempNext = TempNext -> Next) 
    {
        NewNode -> Next = TempNext;
        if (TempNext == Head) Head = NewNode; // Check for empty list
        else if (NewNode -> Element >= TempNext -> Element) continue; // Check for correct point in list
        else TempPrevious -> Next = NewNode;
        return true;
    }

    // If execution reaches this point, then the new node goes at the end of the list    
    TempPrevious -> Next = NewNode;
    return true;
}
```

Whenever I try to insert an element into an empty list using this algorithm, the program returns a segmentation fault. A check with GDB identifies the `TempPrevious -> Next = NewNode;` line at the very end as the cause, but execution shouldn't be reaching there since the `return true` at the end of the `for` loop should return control to the invoking function, but for some reason it isn't. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Off-topic: Using the same naming convention for your types *and* variables makes your code very hard to read.

Comment: @GMan, what are you referring to?

Comment: `const Type& NewElement`, for example, or `TempNext = Head; TempNext != NULL; TempPrevious = TempNext, TempNext = TempNext -> Next`. A quick scan reads "type type type type type type type type" to me; I only know they're values because of the language. Perhaps consider making the first letter of a variable lower case.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll do as you suggest in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that if the list is empty, `TempPrevious` will an uninitialized pointer.  When you try running the `for` loop on an empty list, `TempNext` will immediately be `NULL` and you won't execute the statement `TempPrevious = TempNext`.  Since you never set `TempPrevious` to have a default value, it will be uninitialized, and so the code

```
TempPrevious -> Next = NewNode;
```

Will dereference a garbage pointer, hence your crash.

To fix this, you will either need to special-case the case when the list is empty, or use some other approach to list insertion (perhaps keeping a pointer to the node pointer to rewrite) that gracefully handles insertion into an empty list.

Comment: `TempPrevious` is not initialized at all if the `for` loop body is not executed AFAICT. So not quite a null pointer deref.

Comment: @Mat- Whoops!  Misread the code.  I've updated my answer accordingly.  Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've done C++, but is it because TempPrevious is created but never assigned?